# FooEvents for Woocommerce plugin Issues

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I have installed the Fooevents for Woocommerce plugin for booking ticket functionality on my woocommerce site built with the Solala theme.
[image: Screenshot]

I created two tickets for one event and tried to show the tickets on the front page, but they are not showing on it. How can I solve it?

Comment: Please show how you have created these tickets with a snippet of your work to help resolve your issue.

Comment: Please check these screenshots

Comment: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5y4191okisk37ro/AABt2u51cPUoIgSjwupi7dlPa?dl=0)